# Tool for testing or particularly fuzz-testing JWT validator?

Tags: open-source, software-testing

JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) are an open, industry [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) method for representing claims securely between two parties. There are [numerous  implementations](https://jwt.io/) for JWT verification but it looks like each author is testing his implementation on his own.

Can you recommend a tool or library for testing or particularly fuzz-testing JWT validator?

I would prefer to have a tool or library in Java, Ruby or Python. But many fuzzers I've heard off are GUI tools or command-line tools and I don't care much which language they are in. I would be satisfied if there's at least one.